# Measure time of running SQL job and start another if it exceeds a certain amount

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have a job that usually run for about 17 seconds. Somehow, that job sometimes take hours to run.

I'm looking for a way to measure how long that job have been running and when/if the job has been running for more than 30 minutes it will stop at that step and restart at the same step.

The system I'm running this on is MS SQL.

Comment: Have you done any investigation into why it's running slow _while it's running slow_? Having a job that starts a different job when this happens seems like having an extra spare tire in case your first spare tire is flat. You should figure out why the job is sometimes slow and solve _that problem_. Possibly blocking, maybe conflicting with backups or maintenance, but with zero info about what the job is doing we can only speculate.

Comment: For getting times see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539057/61305 but note that if the very first step is the one that's running long, you may not be able to see this from sysjobhistory. Until you resolve it you may want to add a first step that is just `PRINT 1;` or something, then at least you can check when the last time that step completed successfully and if it's longer than 30 minutes before the last successful run of step 2.

Comment: You need to provide **a lot** more details than that. Explain what the job does and show some code. Given that execution times vary a lot, it could be that other processes are accessing the same tables, causing **locking** issues. Maybe part of the solution would involve **scheduling** the task at a time (night) when DB activity is low.

Comment: Do you have any query plans? What is the code for the job step? Is it being blocked by locking from another query?